# Database of experimental cross sections for atomic collisions

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, scattering-cross-section, data

Does the atomic-physics community keep a comprehensive database of experimental data (cross sections) for atomic collisions?  I am looking for data about Bremsstrahlung, ionization, elastic and inelastic scattering, etc. induced by electrons in the 0-100 MeV range.

For nuclear reactions, the [EXFOR](https://www-nds.iaea.org/exfor/exfor.htm) database provides a good starting point. Does anything similar exist for atomic physics?

Comment: With this sort of thing, you need to be very precise. What sort of matrix elements are you looking for? Is this in bulk or for atoms in vacuum? In general, atomic physics is messier, with a lot more states lying around, so it's much harder to do channel-resolved measurements. (Additionally, 100 MeV is absolutely huge, with a de Broglie wavelength of 0.002 Bohr radii, and ~10,000,000 times a typical ionization potential. If such an electron interacts with an atom at all, it will be to know stuff out in a messy way, I think, though there is indeed room for Bremstrahlung and so on.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I'll buy any matrix element for atoms in any chemical state (although the latter has little importance for high-energy electrons) :-)

Answer (score 1):

there are various databases for this sort of information. In your position I would start with

http://www.vamdc.eu/

which has links to other databases and is currently maintained. It may have more information on molecules than on atoms, but I hope it is useful.

Another database is [Gaphyor](http://gaphyor.lpgp.u-psud.fr/gaphyor/), but an issue with this database is that it does not accept new data and has been fixed since 2005 so the current maintenance of this site is not as much as for VAMDC linked above.

In my experience there is not a single database for all this information - it is an issue that the academic community is grappling with.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but it's longer than a comment and I think it's somewhat valuable so I'll put it here.

Some time ago, I found myself in need of electronic dipole moment transition matrix elements for CO$_2^+$, between the ground state and the first few excited states. I thought to myself: "this is a perfectly well-defined quantity which is not that hard to calculate, and CO$_2$ has been studied to bits, so surely this is out there somewhere; in fact, there ought to be a database of some sort with this sort of thing somewhere". I set out to find this database, and I failed miserably.

The problem was explained to me later on by a (very competent) quantum chemist. The transition matrix elements depend on the electronic eigenstates, and these in turn depend, sometimes quite sensitively, on the nuclear coordinates. This means that asking for the electronic DTMEs is not in fact a well-defined question if you don't specify what you want to do with the nuclei. Do you take the DTME at the bottom of the well? At the experimental positions? Averaged over the nuclear ground state? Averaged over some other nuclear eigenstate? These variations will change the answer slightly. For the accuracy I needed this was not a problem, but it does sentence any attempt at a such a database to infeasibility, because you'd need data on a complete set of nuclear coordinates for this to be useful, and that is not something reasonable to ask of the literature.

---

This is why I said you need to be very precise, because being vague on this sort of thing can really kill you. What matrix elements do you want *exactly*? What operators, and sandwiched between what sort of states? What sort of experiments are you thinking about? Any information you can provide to bring down the solution space will make it much more likely that you find what you're looking for.

Nuclear physics is, in many ways, very contained, in the sense that the things you can do are sort of limited at shooting Xs at a target of Y and seeing what comes out. Since the experiment tends to not be useful unless you have good control over the velocity of the Xs and good discrimination of what comes out, that's what you do. To top it off, the toolbox of available types of Xs is not really that broad.

None of these aspects hold for atomic and molecular physics. The types of experiments you might run are wide and varied, and the sorts of structural and dynamical information you might be interested in is similarly broad. This makes it much harder (though not impossible) to compile databases of the sort of information you're looking for.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have the impression that your objections mainly concern the availability of  a database of *theoretical* predictions. The *experimental* transition matrix elements, to get back to your example, do not care about how you decide to describe the nuclei. A dipole transition matrix is something that in principle you can measure directly, isn't it?

Comment: My main point is that atomic and molecular physics are messier than nuclear physics and do not necessarily have the large runs of very similar experiments that make the nuclear physics databases so successful. (On the DTMEs - you can't really; if doing it optically you'd measure oscillator strength. And there's a million ways you might do that.)

Comment: It's funny that you say that atomic and molecular physics are messier than nuclear physics; I have exactly the opposite impression. I guess this is due to the fact that each of us underestimates the complexity of the other field. My impression comes from the fact that both fields have to deal with the complexity of the N-body problem, but *in addition* the nucleon-nucleon interaction is much more complex that the electromagnetic one.

Comment: The difference is what 'messy' means. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not aware of nuclear-physics experiments that are not based on [the accelerator collide-and-see principle](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3155). The inner workings of your box may be very complicated, but its input and output modes are relatively limited from an experimental viewpoint.

Comment: There are plenty of experiments dedicated to the study of nuclear structure. True, you might have to produce a specific nucleus by nuclear reaction, but the tricky part of the experiment is measuring e.g. its mass or its level structure. The nuclear-reaction part is essentially taken for granted.

Answer (score 0):

You question title is broad enough that folks might find these resources useful, even though they do not address your specific electron-atom scattering in the body of the questions.

Brookhaven National Laboratory hosts the National Nuclear Data Center, which includes a variety of data bases that they maintain for the nuclear physics community.  It can be found at [NNDC](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/).  It includes atomic mass data, neutron reaction, evaluated nuclear reaction data files, nuclear structure, decay data, etc.

Triangle Universities Nuclear Laboratory ([TUNL](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/index.shtml)) also has a number of links.  Of particular interest is they are putting nuclear energy diagrams on line.

Comment: These are nuclear-data databases, though.

Comment: As noted in the body, that is in response to the question title, not the clarification in the question itself. Someone searching later on may find it useful, even if it isn't electron-atom cross sections.

Comment: Still, the title says "atomic collisions", not "nuclear". Oh wait, I get it. People use "atomic" when they mean "nuclear".